# Jakarta and Glassfish - Basic authentication works, Form authentication do not

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, glassfish, j-security-check

I am pretty new into web development. Currently I am trying to do an Form Based Authentication on my Jakarta app. I managed to create a realm on Glassfish 6.0.0  and to integrate it on the web.xml descriptor. I managed to make the Basic Authentication work, but when I try it to change to Form Authentication I get an 403 status code ever time I want to login. I got the following error every time I send a POST request to j_security_check with good credentials, along with 403 status code:

> ***WEB9102: Web Login Failed:
> com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException

: Login failed: Security Exception*** which doesn't say to much for me.

I wanted to create an Form Authentication in order to use j_security_check to login using form-data format from Postman. If I can not do this, is there a way to create a custom endpoint to send a request in order to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

I found out a method to do what I needed for the moment. I just sent parameters in URL. For now it is perfect, even though the security suffer with this method.